# Servlet Forwarding to jsp Goes Into Infinite Loop

Tags: jsp, servlets, root, web.xml, forward

I have a web app that I am doing for school and I am running into an issue with forwarding to '/index.jsp', where index.jsp is located right under the web app root, localhost:8080/index.jsp. I know it has something to do with the context and the way I am directing things but I cannot figure this out.

Here is my web.xml, where I direct to my controller.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/action/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have a banner that goes across all jsps, including the index.jsp home page that among other things has a link to the home page(which is the index.jsp).

```
<li><a class="active" href="/action/index.jsp">Home</a></li>
```

When I click on the home page link that essentially just goes to itself, the doGet method in the controller returns the view to go to as '/index.jsp', which I thought meant back to the home page which is under the web app root. So I perform a forward:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(view).forward(request,response);
```

But the request just keeps on looping through my doGet method. I thought forwarding using the requestDispatcher does forwarding relative to the web app root but is it doing it in relation to '/action/...' instead? I can forward to a jsp in the WEB-INF folder using '/WEB-INF/some.jsp' but I just can't forward to index.jsp, which happens to be the only jsp not in WEB-INF and under the web app root. Can someone clear up what is happening?

Comment: Are you redirecting to `index.jsp` or `/index.jsp`? And what do you intend to be handling `/action/*.jsp` - your controller or the JSP servlet? I'd argue that you shouldn't use the jsp suffix on actions that your controller handles to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: Apparently `view` variable matches `/action/*` path. Just make sure `view` variable only refers `/WEB-INF` resources.

Comment: @Olaf, I am forwarding to '/index.jsp', which is saved in the view variable. When the link is clicked the controller receives it because the web.xml maps '/action/*' to the controller class. This class looks at the path info does things based upon that and then returns a string representing the view to be either forwarded to or redirected. In this case it is supposed to just go back to and display the index.jsp page but it doesn't

Comment: @Balus, yeah it seems that way but not sure why. And as you said I can refer to WEB-INF resources via view forwarding but if I use redirect I can go to /index.jsp. I am not sure why forwarding works for /WEB-INF/some.jsp but not /index.jsp. . .

Comment: Because it matches the servlet's URL pattern and thus it gets invoked again?

Comment: I guess that is just the answer and then I guess then by inference forwarding is relation not to the web-app root but to the 'root' of whatever context you are in, in my case '/action/'